# Old forgotten unlabeled duplicates?

Tags: discussion, questions, flagging, exact-duplicates

[How to recenter an object's origin?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin)

[Moving the 'center of the object' to the actual center…](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44950/moving-the-center-of-the-object-to-the-actual-center)

Is it useful to flag old duplicates as duplicates?
Should I just ignore them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, go ahead and mark it as a duplicate. (I just closed the linked question as duplicate.)

Usually, there is no harm in adding links to a place where other answers may help - the age of the question does not matter. If it has been answered else where on this site, why not point others to it?

There is an added bonus to marking old questions like that, which is that you bring added attention to these old questions. So yes go ahead and

Do bear in mind that all the same "rules" apply, they really have to be duplicates (again age does not matter).